# How to Create Custom Empty okhttp3.Response?

Tags: okhttp

PROBLEM: Method returns Response, sometimes null, if request call fails. Error message from exception should be added to returned Response manually.

RESEARCH:

```
Request request;
Response response = null;

  try {

    response =
      client
        .newCall(request)
        .execute();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    response = ... // Need to instantiate manually.
  }
```

QUESTION: **How to create empty Response instance to change its null value**?

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin language example:

```
val response = Response.Builder()
            .request(chain.request())
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
            .code(200)
            .message("success")
            .header("MOCKED_HEADER_KEY", "MOCKED_HEADER_VALUE")
            .body("mocked body".toResponseBody("text/html".toMediaTypeOrNull()))
            .build()
```

**request**, **protocol**, **message** properties required (to avoid IllegalStateException).

Answer (score 0):

This you may need:

```
Response.Builder builder = new Response.Builder();
//builder.code(200).message("success").body(...);
response = builder.build();
```

Though, response is empty, but you could use Builder to set any you need values.

Comment: But this crashed with `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: inside build there is a check , `if (request == null) throw new IllegalStateException("request == null");`